# Cannot execute remote binary file in eshell

Tags: emacs, tramp, eshell

I connected Emacs to a virtual machine via Eshell, using Tramp. I tried to execute a binary file at the current directory, but Eshell cannot see that file, even though it is right there. The output returned is like this:

```
/ssh:hwswi:/home/auser/course-materials/lab0 $ ./arrays
./arrays: command not found
```

For binaries within `$PATH`, Eshell has no problem.

**Edit**: if I execute it like this, then Eshell executes fine.

`/ssh:hwswi:/home/auser/course-materials/lab0/arrays`

Comment: How about just typing `arrays` -- **without** `./` in front of it?  From the error message, it appears that for some reason, it thinks you want to call a program **named** `./arrays` -- i.e., it doesn't recognize `./` as being a special way of launching an executable in the working directory.

Comment: @lawlist the result is still "command not found". If I use Dired, I can execute fine. I guess I have to use Dired for remote file system.

Answer (score 1):

- have execute bits of array been set?  if no, set them, or run the appropriate interpreter and load array with it.
- does she she-bang line of array reference an actually existing interpreter? if not, fix she-bang
- if array is a binary executable, not a script, make sure it has been compiled for the proper architecture. the file utility is helpful for this.
- try to specify full path, instead of assuming that executable resides in current directory

Comment: The binary runs file in the virtual machine, but I cannot run it in eshell prompt, at that exact directory. It's a binary executable, not a shell script.

Comment: i have added another item to my answer

Comment: But my Eshell prompt is actually inside the directory that contains the executable. If I was in my local machine, it would execute file. Probably I should file a bug report.

Comment: try to symlink the executable into a directory in PATH